# how to get weather report of a my current location

Tags: iphone

i need to get weather report of my current location.

For Example if i am at xyz location then i need to get weather report of xyz location,And if i am in abc location  i need to get weather report of abc location.

i heard that Apple does n't any services regarding weather reports.For this we need to use third party services.

Is there any free weather report services to use in my application.

Can any one please help me.

Thank u in advance.

Comment: Have you tried Googling "weather forecast API"?

Comment: I did n't think why my question put -1.the person who give - ve vote for me please add comment why my question -ve vote,then i can rectify it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, yahoo provides a weather service - on the iPhone you need to

1. get your longitude & latitude using CoreLocation
2. use

http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select+place+from+flickr.places+where+lat=%f+and+lon=%f

to get a woeid (WhereOnEarth ID)

1. use

   http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=%@&u=c

to get your weather report

Comment: <description>Cannot find required keys in where clause;  got 'lon, lat', expecting required keys: (api_key,query) OR (lon,api_key,lat)</description>

Answer (score 0):

There is a service from weather.com , I used this for my online application agrosenti.cloudapp.net.

And its quite easy to use. You have to download the documention and follow the guidlines.

weather forecast API is a good option.

If you need more APIs nad further help please tell me.

Comment: Thank u vKline,How can i use this in my iphone application.

Comment: @MaheshBabu Well see the documentation also check http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/39414-google-weather-api-parse-xml.html